# NullPointerException while accessing an instance of Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-config

I am trying to use Spring JDBCTemplate class to access database. 
As a first tutorial, I have used xml spring configuration file and everything works as expected. 
Now, I am trying to use `@Configuration` and created `DataSource` and `JdbcTemplate` instances through `@Bean` annotation within this file. But, I get a NullPointerException at `int result = template.update(sql);`

I am sure I have done a silly mistake. Was wondering what it could be.

The code is as follows.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringJDBCAnnotation {

@Autowired
static JdbcTemplate template;

@Autowired
static DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/organization");
    ds.setUsername("root");
    ds.setPassword("test");
    return ds;
}

@Bean
JdbcTemplate template() {
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate();
    template.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return template;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String sql = "insert into employee values(1, 'Tom', 'Cruise')";
    int result = template.update(sql);
    System.out.println("# of records inserted : " + result);


}

}
```

Comment: Because you did not start Spring.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Comment: Don’t make these member fields static. Btw check out spring boot tutorials on spring.io blog.

Comment: @NathanHughes These are accessed in the main() method and hence had to be declared as static. This is merely an exercise.

Comment: @Sara Well, it's a fine exercise in how not to use Spring, showing how Spring cannot do anything unless you initialize Spring first. You need to let Spring create *objects* that need to be autowired (implies that Spring cannot autowire `static` fields).

Comment: Getting away from static variable evilness is a big part of why spring was created. you need to instantiate an applicationcontext like everybody is telling you, then retrieve the beans from that.

Comment: @NathanHughes Don't retrieve beans, inject them.

Comment: @chrylis: yes. Retrieve one bean from the context and the rest will be injected. Again, OP: get a better tutorial.

Comment: @NathanHughes I have answered this question. This works as intended. Can you please review it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application Context needs to be obtained whenever we need to create beans or autowire them.

Since this is Java based configuration, it is retrieved as follows.

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringJDBCAnnotation.class);
```

and the beans needs to be accessed from the context as usual.

```
JdbcTemplate template = context.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);
```